# How to provide permissions to particular user for accessing web page in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I created one page named as `Welcome.aspx`. On that page I added one button,on that button click event page should be redirect to another page i.e `UserRegisteration.aspx` page but that `UserRegisteration.aspx` page should be accessible to some particular user like Team Lead,Manager. If the user other than that click on that button and try to access `UserRegisteration.aspx` page then error message should generate.

Please suggest me how to achieve above requirement?? Thanks in advance

Comment: how you identify user type?

Comment: Based on the roles like Team Lead,Manager

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this button code:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
            string userType = "Team Lead"; // set user type
            if (userType=="Team Lead" || userType=="Manager")
            {
                Response.Redirect("UserRegisteration.aspx"); // redirects to specified page
            }
            else
            {
                // shows error message
                ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "", "alert('You are not a valid user!')", true);
            }

    }
```

Comment: Thanks for solution but how to identify which particular user clicked the button?? Whether the user is normal one or manager and team lead

Comment: in your login page you can specify the userType and then store it in sesseion.